# fmi2GetFMUState/fmi2SetFMUState supported for Matlab/OpenModelica generated FMUs?

Tags: python, simulink, openmodelica, fmi

I am trying to test a simple fmu to save and restore the states.

For example openmodelica:

```modelica
model modelicatest
input Real In1;
output Real Out1(start=0, fixed=true);
equation
der(Out1) = In1;
end modelicatest;
```

Also for simulink:

[image]

I am using [FMPy](https://github.com/CATIA-Systems/FMPy) to simulate the generated FMUs.

But for OpenModelica v1.14.1 generated FMU, I get the following error when I call `getFMUState` from FMPy:

```
Exception: fmi2GetFMUstate failed with status 3
```

For Simulink (2019b) generated FMU using the built-in exporter, FMU state does not reset (i.e. the output value) when I run `setFMUState`.

Just wondering these functions are supported for OpenModelica and Simulink generated FMUs? or is it FMPy issue?

Comment: OpenModelica FMUs do not support yet this functionality. It is in the plan to add it in some near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to fmi2GetFMUstate/fmi2SetFMUstate, the [FMI Specification](https://github.com/modelica/fmi-standard/releases/download/v2.0.1/FMI-Specification-2.0.1.pdf), section 2.1.8. states:

> These functions are only supported by the FMU, if the optional capability flag `<fmiModelDescription> <ModelExchange / CoSimulation canGetAndSetFMUstate in = "true">` in the XML file is **explicitly** set to true (see sections 3.3.1 and 4.3.1).

You can unzip the fmu file and take a look at the modelDescription.xml file to find out if the flag is set: If it is *false* or not set all, the get and set functions are not supported.

Comment: Just checked it is false for the openmodelica generated fmu and there is none for the simulink generated fmu.